# File.WriteAllText - chr13 and Chr(10) convert into chr(32)

Tags: c#, csv, file

im using following code:

```
    internal string DataTableToCSV(DataTable dtable, char seperator, string exTableName = "")
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            try
            {
                var opts = new CsvDataWriterOptions { Delimiter = seperator };
                
                using (var csvw = CsvDataWriter.Create(sw, opts)) // 
                    csvw.Write(dtable.CreateDataReader());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (exTableName != "")
                exceptionProtocol(exTableName, ex.ToString());
            }
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }


    //write CSV
    File.WriteAllText(path, DataTableToCSV(dTableHelper, ';', tableNameFromRow), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

the code works as it should, it creates the csv's of database tables.

When he writes the CSV I want to convert chr13 and chr10 (Newline) to Chr32 (space). Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Did you try with _string.Replace_?

Comment: @Steve `String.Replace` is not a universally feasible option when a `StringWriter` can contain many megabytes of text (up to 2GB or more, as it uses non-contiguous chunks in its internal `StringBuilder`).

Comment: `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` <-- Why are you using codepage encoding instead of UTF-8?

Comment: Using `WriteAllText` to write a single `String` value is not the most efficient way to do this: you can _stream_ the text directly to disk without creating huge intermediate string values.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I didn't know the method with stream so I'll take a look.

Comment: value = value.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " "); would I cover both chr(10), chr(13) with System.Environment.NewLine?